# GitHub projects and job searching

Tags: interviewing, resume, job-search, career-development

I have a fairly large software project and a few small projects that I'm about to put on GitHub. The large project is not ready for release, and I continue to work on it intermittently. I'm pretty proud of what it can do so far, and I had been postponing putting it on GitHub due to a recurring case of not-complete-enough syndrome. Now I've accelerated my plans because I want to present my project to prospective employers, as I'm beginning to test the software job market again for the first time in a few years.

My question: Is there any reason why I might not want to advertise my project on my resume and perhaps show it to a prospective employer? Even a flawed or incomplete project can serve as a springboard for productive discussion about architecture, choice of technology, etc... Right? I'm a full time engineer, so I can fall back on the standard on-the-job accomplishments... but I think this extra little something would be a nice touch. Or can a project be in a state such that it might work against me before there is a chance to discuss?

Comment: Is this a project you have done as part of your current role?

Answer (score 1):

How do you think someone is going to review your project? They'll probably focus on code structure and not go through the app installation like a typical user (esp. if it is large) looking for flaws and limited functionality.

In a cover letter, focus on the status of the project and the future work you plan on doing. This should put things into perspective. You could include other documents that outline how you plan on structuring the additions, so people can see how you plan as well as code.

Comment: Yes I do agree with this. What we did was we didn't even compile the stuff. We just looked at the code structure, and see if we saw any sort of structure or discipline being followed. A huge plus is using frameworks and showing you have an understanding of other people's code which is important. It won't land you a job, but it will impress them enough to call you in for a interview at best. They won't know if it's actually your code and would just have to take your word for it.

Answer (score 1):

It could help. At my current company, and past company, we looked at any and all links provided by in a resume. We even pass the name into a search engine to see if anything comes up. I assume this is common practice in the tech industries but I'm not entirely sure.

At best, I'd say it would at least land you a potential interview. I don't think it will increase your chances of getting a job but I do think it will certainly help get you in the door sooner than others and on top of that they'd have a "good feeling" about you. The key thing will be to wow them at the interview and it'll seal the deal for you.

That is assuming unless your product is helping millions and you're a huge success with your product. That would probably put you in the area of "must have" person.